# Alternative graphic drivers?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, xorg, radeon

My graphics graphics card is a Radeon HD 4250 and ATI has dropped the support for x-server version higher than 1.12. Are there any alternative graphic drivers I can use besides the opensource driver, Gallium 0.4. If not what's the best config I can do to boost performance so that it's similar to the proprietary driver. I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 64bit, and my graphics are: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you, I got stuck with the open source driver, but I use this PPA that has some tweaking added to the drivers, which really increases performance and stability:

The PPA is [here](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers/).

To install the drivers:

```
sudo apt-add-repository  ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get  update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

And reboot.

If you have any problem, just purge the ppa:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

Comment: By the way, I've tried all kind of versions of the fglrx closed drivers, deb, run, generate deb's from the installer. I've always ended up with a broken Xorg. So as far as I know this is the only working driver for Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: I also tried downgrading my Xorg but that slowly started breaking down my system after a while.

Comment: Is hardware acceleration enabled?

Comment: Yes it is. While not perfect, I can play most of 3D games.